# Error when trying to load a module into the kernel

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-kernel

I'm trying to load a kernel module into the kernel by running the following command,

```
`anthony@ubuntu:~/Desktop/kmaldetect/loadable_kernel_module$ make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build
```

This is the error that i get:

```
make: Entering directory /usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-25-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:129: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
Makefile:669: Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_REGULAR: -fstack-protector not supported by compiler
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by `arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/asm/syscalls_32.h'.  Stop.
make: *** [archheaders] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-25-generic'
```

Maybe someone could help me out.
All help is appreciated.

Comment: You have several issues: 1. This command builds *kernel itself* instead of the module. For build module you need append `M=$(PWD) modules` or like. 2. Before build kernel module, you need to build kernel itself. 3. As your machine is x86_64, you needn't `CONFIG_X86_X32` option in kernel's `.config` file. Also, you probably need to disable `CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_REGULAR` option.

Answer (score 0):

The Makefile in kmaldetect/loadable_kernel_module seems correct, doesn't simply running `make` there work?